# What ways to perform CRUD operations in Scala with mongoDB

Tags: scala, mongodb

what are the methods/drivers i can use to perform CRUD operations? Atm, i am only successful with the Create function, ie

```
DBObbject.put("field","value")
```

Common sense suggests that find() should stand for retrieve, but using it gives the following error

```
value find is not a member of com.mongodb.BasicDBObject
```

All and any help appreciated.

EDIT #1:

I also was able to perform retrieve, but I retrieved the whole document, and not a specific field.

```
var mongo = new Mongo()
var databaseName = mongo.getDB("DBName")
var collectionName = databaseName.getCollection("namecollection")
var testdbObject = new BasicDBObject()

testdbObject.put("userId", "5678")
var cursor = collectionName.find(testdbObject)

println(cursor.next())
```

EDIT #2: Field based retrieval. IMO, Can put inside loop and print all. Havent tried the loop thing.

```
var result = collectionName.findOne()
println(result.get("userId").toString)
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the benefit of the programming public: CRD operations.

The create operation:

```
def addToMongo(): Unit = {    
        dbObject.put("name", "mongo")
        dbObject.put("type", "db")        
        collectionName.insert(dbObject)
     }
```

The retrieve operation:

```
def retrieveMongo(): Unit = {    
    var result = collectionName.findOne()
    println(result.get("fieldName").toString)

  }
```

The Delete Operation.

```
def deleteMongo(): Unit = {
    var deleteQuery = new BasicDBObject
    var tempObject = new BasicDBObject
    deleteQuery.put("requestType", "temp");
  var cursor = new DBCursor(collectionName, deleteQuery, tempObject)
    while (cursor.hasNext()) {
      collectionName.remove(cursor.next())
    }
```

I was unable to come-up with a solution for the Update. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 2):

The presentation by Brendan McAdams at this [link](http://vimeo.com/14090025) will give you most of the idea of how to use scala+mongoDB together.